# Script that runs in background gets stopped when theres a popUp

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript method that needs to run in the background

```
window.setInterval(function(){
 validateCaseStatus();
}, 3000);
```

On the same page I have a button that asks the user if he wants to submit uploaded documents. But I noticed when the popUp msg(alert) is up the script on the page wont run.

Is there a way to keep the script running?

I use this method to check if the case status is changed and disable window.onbeforeunload. 
My question is if theres a way I can keep the script above running even when a popUp alert is shown.

```
//cancels onbefore close popup when docs are submitted
function validateCaseStatus(){

     caseStatus = sforce.apex.execute("IFAP_WebService","CheckCaseStatus", {!$caseId});  

    if (caseStatus == "Uploaded" || caseStatus == "Submitted")
    {
         submitted = true; 
        window.onbeforeunload  = null;
        validateCaseStatus = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you use `alert` for ?

Comment: The alert is to ask the user if he is sure he wants to submit documents when he presses on the button, this button refreshes the page afterwards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using WebWorkers. It's a new html5 concept, and requires a bit more work, but they are very easy to understand and very helpful. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_web_workers http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/ and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: I have many restrictions on the platform I'm using and I can only use html and js on that page.

Comment: (but they aren't supported in all current browsers for sure... http://caniuse.com/#search=WebWorkers)

Comment: Create a fallback for IE and I assume that your website isn't targeting mobile viewers. Otherwise, you should be fine.

Comment: well that's not good then :S I need something that works at least for the major 3 browsers including IE :S !

Comment: Well then, it would be nice if you showed us the rest of your code.

Comment: @Kpower Can I make the webworkers update variables on my current page?

Comment: Yes, they probably will. I'd suggest you read the links though. They'll be able to explain the concept much better than me.